# reduce code for ternary operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

```
ng-init="data.postingType ? data.postingType : ''"
```

This is my code is there any way to reduce my code im writing this `data.postingType` two times is it possible to make it simple

like

```
ng-init="data.postingType ? PrintExistData : ''"         //not valid..?
```

my controller:

```
var  data.postingType ='somehing is inside which is string';
```

Comment: what is the truthy value of `data.postingType` ?

Comment: its a string can be anything

Comment: You could use `data.postingType || ""`

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? Doesn't make sense. You aren't assigning anything

Comment: @charlietfl makes perfect sense, he wants to evaluate the first parameter and return it if its `non-falsey`, otherwise return a blank string.

Comment: @Derek return to where?

Comment: to the `ng-init` attribute

Comment: @Derek that's not how ng-init works. It is only used for occasional business logic ....and gets abused a lot https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: @charlietfl please note this is an angular specific `HTML` attribute, not plain javascript

Comment: I am fully aware of that. With no variable assignment there is no access to what it returns and the expression shown does nothing

Comment: @charlietfl oh yeah, I've seen some really hacky stuff done with `ng-init`, so it wouldn't surprise me if this actually worked

Comment: @Derek that's why I asked what was expected from it. To me it still makes no sense and whatever it is probably belongs in controller

Comment: @Derek  thnx for the answer I was expecting this. `data.postingType || ""`

Comment: Still makes no sense putting that statement in ng-init. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i looked for

```
data.postingType || ""
```